# Query for which my.ini in use

Tags: mysql, configuration

Is it possible to query mysql server to know which configuration file is in use? Sometimes, my.cnf, my.ini.

```
SHOW VARIABLES; -- does not have enough information here for my.ini path
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that, because once the config is loaded on startup, it is no longer used.

MySQL uses a deterministic algorithm for searching for a config file. You can see it [on the MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html) (the first table is for Windows).

Two things you can do is: check which options are loaded by default: use `--print-defaults`:

```
mysqld --print-defaults
mysqld would have been started with the following arguments:
--log_bin
```

(in this case, I have `log_bin` in my configuration file).

[Force manually a configuration file to be loaded](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-file-options.html) with the parameter `--defaults-file`:

```
mysqld --defaults-file=C:\my\path\to\my.ini
```